# Resolver in graphql on relation

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, apollo, apollo-server

I would like to execute this request, to have all buckets with specific language :

```
{
   buckets{
      id,
      code,
      language(id:1){
         code
      }
   }
}
```

But I have this response :

```
{
  "data": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "language": {
          "code": "FR"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "language": {
          "code": "FR"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "language": "FR" <= Real value "EN"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "language": "FR" <= Real value "EN"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to have only the bucket with language id selected :

```
{
  "data": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "language": {
          "code": "FR"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "language": {
          "code": "FR"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**schema.js**

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

export const typeDefs = gql`

  # Language
  type Language {
    id: Int!
    name: String
    code: String
    is_active: Boolean
  }

  # Bucket
  type Bucket {
    id: Int!,
    code: String
    language(id: Int): Language
  }

  # query for types
  type Query {
    buckets: [Bucket]
  }

  schema {
    query: Query
  }
`;

export default typeDefs;
```

**resolvers.js**

```
import GraphQLDate from 'graphql-date';
import { Bucket, Language } from './connectors';

export const resolvers = {
    Date: GraphQLDate,
    Query: {
        buckets(_, args) {
            return Bucket.findAll({
                where: args,
                order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
            });
        }
    },
    Bucket: {
       language(bucket, {id}) {
           console.log('resolver id', id);
           const where = {id: bucket.fk_language_id };

           if (id) {
               where.id = id
           }

           return Language.findOne({
               where: where,
           });
       },
   }
};

export default resolvers;
```

**connectors.js**

```
...

// define language
const LanguageModel = db.define('language', {
    name     : {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    code     : {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    is_active: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN}
});

// define bucket
const BucketModel = db.define('bucket', {
    code     : {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    is_active: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN}
});

BucketModel.belongsTo(LanguageModel, {
    foreignKey: 'fk_language_id'
});

LanguageModel.hasMany(BucketModel, {
    foreignKey: 'id'
});

...
```

My database is very simple, just two tables Language and Bucket.

**Database**

Language

> id | name | code | is_active

Bucket

> id | fk_language_id | code | created_at | updated_at

With this request :

```
{
buckets{
    id,
  language{
    code
  }
  }
}
```

I have this result :

```
{
  "data": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "language": {
          "code": "FR"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "language": {
          "code": "FR"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "language": {
          "code": "EN"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "language": {
          "code": "EN"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: are you pretty sure this is happening when you include the ID in the query?

```
if (id) {
  where.id = id
}
```

Comment: Are you getting "id" in your resolver ? Because i don't see any "input" in schema.

Comment: @masmerino I updated my code with the simple request without specific id on language

Comment: let's do a quick test: could you change your query to it:
{
buckets(filter: languaje: { id: 1}){
    id,
  language {
    code
  }
  }
}

Comment: Prisma and grapql cool support filters by this way :)

Comment: @masmerino I tried to execute { 
  buckets(filter: language: { id: 1}){
    id, 
    language{ 
      code
    }
  } 
} but nothing, the request doesn't launch

Comment: go it, let me try something else

Comment: @AmitBhoyar in my schema I have this : type Bucket {
    id: Int!,
    code: String
    language(id: Int): Language
  }

Comment: @JérémieChazelle, Not sure at this point but after overlooking, I think you want to filter on Bucket list not on language list so where  clause should go in Bucket.findAll({ where :{ id: yourId}}). Also schema should send filter on top level(bucket).

Comment: @AmitBhoyar do you have an exemple with code please ?